# Angular @ngx-pwa/local-storage is not working

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am trying to store data in the browser's local storage using 
        [@ngx-pwa/local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage) as it provides additional `RxJs` operators on top of regular/common local storage.

versions

```
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
        "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^6.2.4"
```

component/service:

```
       constructor(private storage: LocalStorage) {}
         /// *** /////

        const user: User = { firstName: 'lorem', lastName: 'ipsum' };
        this.storage.setItem('user', user).subscribe(() => {});
```

In the browser's Application/Local Storage => data is empty.

Comment: I think the name of the library is confusing. It is called localStorage but it uses the IndexedDB  ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ngx-pwa/local-storage` uses `indexedDB` internally to make the operations asynchronous.

Therefore, when you perform asynchronous storing operations, it is stored in `indexedDB`. So you should check the corresponding tab:

```
Application -> IndexedDB -> ngStorage -> localStorage
```

*Note that this path could change based on configurations*

From official docs:

> The localStorage API is simple to use but synchronous, so if you use
>   it too often, your app will soon begin to freeze.
>
> The indexedDB API is asynchronous and efficient, but it's a mess to
>   use: you'll soon be caught by the callback hell, as it does not
>   support Promises yet.
>
> Mozilla has done a very great job with the localForage library: a
>   simple API based on native localStorage, but internally stored via the
>   asynchronous indexedDB for performance. But it's built in ES5 old
>   school way and then it's a mess to include into Angular.
>
> This module is based on the same idea as localForage, but built in
>   ES6+ and additionally wrapped into RxJS Observables to be homogeneous
>   with other Angular modules.